# Which data structure/algorithm can find the smallest node on a path of a dynamic MST (or a rooted tree)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

On a given MST (or a rooted tree), we can perform these tasks:

1. To all nodes in a given subtree rooted at x add value A.

   ```
   [Answered] Using Euclidean path, first and last appearance of x.
   ```
2. Report maximum value on the path from i to j.

Which data structure/algorithm will take the smallest time for both queries ?
I do not need code for this. I only want to know the idea behind the solution.

Comment: I'll post my wrong answer as a commentary, since it helps with the first part: you can use the Euler tour in combination with segment trees to efficiently do (1). Not sure about (2) though.

Comment: Thanks for the half answer :) *no sarcasm*

Comment: Interesting question. Euler tour trees are great for augmenting entire subtrees, but can't do paths. Link/cut trees can augment paths, but can't do subtrees. I wonder if there's an existing data structure that does both?

Comment: @templatetypedef There's a two-line (roughly) modification to link/cut trees that will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a generalized Sleator--Tarjan tree that can provide both operations in logarithmic time and several others besides (http://www.davideisenstat.com/dtree/). The linked implementation is amortized, but there's no reason a worst-case version couldn't be done other than practical inefficiency. Please talk to me if you ever consider writing your own; there's a lot of complexity there that may be unnecessary for your use case.

To describe the idea at a very high level requires a thumbnail sketch of how S--T trees are organized. We root the tree somewhere and decompose it into disjoint paths. Each of the paths is stored as a splay tree where each data structural node stores the maximum of its data structural subtree. The S--T operations allow the path collection to be manipulated to include the query path (Expose and Evert one end, then Expose the other). The splay tree also allows a value to be added to all of its nodes (i.e., a whole path). The trick relative to the original S--T paper is that the paths other than the one currently exposed can be updated lazily from their parent path, allowing subtree updates.

You could also look at a top tree implementation, but I personally find the top tree interface to be difficult to reason about, and the existing implementation of which I'm aware is significantly less efficient in practice.

Comment: How do you update subtrees with a new added weight in a Sleator-Tarjan tree? I'm not sure I see how to do that.

Comment: @templatetypedef It suffices to change the whole tree, because we can cut and relink. The trick is to change how the deltas propagate. Normally they only propagate to legitimate children. In the modified concrete tree, they propagate via bastards as well, so that the whole tree is affected. This miraculously does not screw up the delta max field.